# Where clause is not set up properly

Tags: sql-server

I have a long query, a part of this is based on the `@Amount` parameter.
If the `@Amount` is null, so any result with any amount should come up, otherwise only results that one of their amounts is greater than the `@Amount` parameter should come up.

```
@Amount varchar(20)= NULL

SELECT .....
Format(T1.Amount,'c','en-us') as Amount1, format(T2.Amount, 'c', 'en-us') as Amount2
FROM Table1
WHERE  .....
and ((@Amount is  null) or (Cast(T1.Amount as varchar)>= @Amount) or (Cast(T2.Amount as varchar)>= @Amount))
```

This is not working properly:

- If the `@Amount` parameter is not null, the amounts on the results that come up are less than the amount specified in the `@Amount` parameter.
- if the `@Amount` parameter is null, not all results come up.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WHERE  .....
AND ( 
      ( T1.Amount>= CAST(@Amount AS INT) 
        OR T2.Amount >= CAST(@Amount AS INT)  
      ) 
     AND @Amount IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

No need to filter by amount if `@Amount` is NULL so remove `(@Amount is  null)` from WHERE clause.
Filtering will be done only when `@Amount` does not have `NULL` value.

**EDIT**

If T1.Amount and T2.Amount have numeric datatype (INT , Decimal etc) than comparing by casting to VARCHAR is incorrect . A **Varchar** value 1000 is smaller than 900.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve the second issue but I still have problems with wrong results that come up (their amounts are less than the amount specified in the parameter), I think it has something to do with the `varchar`, is it possible to compare amounts when they are of type `varchar`?

Comment: When you say wrong results are those that have amount less than specified in parameter , it  would be that T1.Amount is less than value in `@Amount` but T2.amount value would be greater or vice versa. This is becuase `OR` is used between the conditions comparing amounts i.e. `Cast(T1.Amount as varchar)>= @Amount 
        OR Cast(T2.Amount as varchar)>= @Amount `

Comment: I know what `or` means, but both amounts are less than the amount specified in parameter...

Comment: is amount less in both columsn when @Amount is Not null ?

Comment: Exactly.It looks like it doesn't consider the `@Amount` parameter.

Comment: then this is coming because of some other condition which has OR . can you post complete conditions in WHERE clause ?

Comment: In the first place why are casting numeric values to string....? compare numbers with number...it will solve your problem.

Comment: Also when size is not specified in CAST function , default size of 30 is used. Please check this also

Comment: @mh2017 as per your comment, the casting is the issue, the problem is that I have to get the `@Amount` parameter as a string.. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You bring parameter as string and then before using in query , cast the @amount parameter to INT.

Comment: check edited answer, instead of casting T1,amount and T2.Amount columns to varchar , cast @Amount parameter to INT , assuming both the columns have INT datatype